# ROS Twist Mux Figuring Out which Channel is Selected

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am working with the ROS twist mux package http://wiki.ros.org/twist_mux and am writing a program that needs to know which channel of the twist mux is selected. Is there an easy way to do this or does anyone know of a good work around if an easy way does not exist? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353442/ros-twist-mux-figuring-out-which-channel-is-selected/) by [mequi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49860/mequi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn Thanks. I decided to just go ahead and implement the feature myself. https://github.com/ros-teleop/twist_mux/pull/20

---

Originally posted by [mequi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49860/mequi/) with karma: 111 on 2020-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-29**:
Nit: until your PR is merged, your answer is not actually *the* answer.